# Highcharts exporting over HTTPS

Tags: highcharts

Currently using the highcharts built in exporting (which sends to their server) breaks HTTPS. Our application is served over HTTPS. Is there a way to not break HTTPS without using your own exporting server?
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we don't offer export server via SSL, but your can prepare your own exporting server.

http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, I thought it would be the case:) Do you have any plans to support SSL?

Comment: At this moemnt it is possible.

Comment: @SebastianBochan : Can you please provide any link or reference to make it possible. We tried to shift the product from HTTP to HTTPS, but we are facing issues. One of the error : Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined

Comment: If you mean exporting tools this is avaiable here: https://export.highcharts.com/

Comment: @SebastianBochan Highcharts isn't providing https export or something changed?

Comment: It is still supported: url: https://export.highcharts.com/, set the url by [exporting.url](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.url) parameter.